# How to block IP address for certain period of time (24 hours)

Tags: php, wordpress, web, ip

I have a website page that will, on visit, redirect you to random picture from my website using this script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "http://localhost/dir/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo.png";
urls[1] = "http://localhost/dir/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo2.png";
urls[2] = "http://localhost/dir/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo3.png";
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);

window.location = urls[random];

</script>
```

But, before that I want to limit users so that they can visit my page only once per day (24h) by blocking their IP address.

Is that doable or there is a better way?

Comment: So, they load the webpage once, and then they can't access it again for an entire day? Seems pretty draconian and impractical.

Comment: I will give users some "product" and I want to give it once a day :)

Comment: Then perhaps you rather want to remember which "product" you gave them that day and only continue showing them that one product the rest of the day? Blocking the IP means if I slip on my keyboard and close the tab too fast then I can't correct that silly mistake and see it again for the rest of the day…

Comment: That is good point.
Way of doing that?

Comment: An `IP` doesn't represent a user. An IP can have hundreds of users behind it.

Comment: "Way of doing that?"  It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO then make an attempt. If you still have trouble, please come back with your code and explain what you have tried in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It is better do the restriction on server. For example in PHP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].